# Multi-table insert from single POST request in .NET Core & Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Are there common design patterns, libraries or other solutions that allow for a performant multi-table insert from a single POST request in a .NET Core MVC with Entity Framework?

Comment: Why do you think your use case would be substantially different from doing an insert on just a single table from your C# code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good question, the database is normalized. Structuring it that way will lead to issues down the road.

Comment: SQL Server will only allow a single table to be inserted into (or deleted from or updated) in a single command.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to simply save multiple times in same post? For example: 

`[HttpPost] 
public IActionResult PostAllocation([FromBody] Vehicle myCar) 
{
  _myDbContext.Table1.Add(car.model); 
  _myDbContext.SaveChanges(); 
  _myDbContext.Table2.Add(car.make); 
  _myDbContext.SaveChanges(); 
  // and insert many times as you like with finally returning Status Code of your choice... 
  return StatusCode(201); 
}`

Comment: @JasonA.Long Okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mausam yeah I think that is best I can do in this case, thank you for the help.